# Self-Implemented Exception error

Tags: java

I cant seem to get my program to make it passed my self implemented exception. I've tested it without this exception and it works fine. For some reason though, my `If` with the x%2's statement inside my `factorial` method is always being executed even when the conditions are met (like when I use 5 as my x value, which should be sufficient to bypass this and move along to the factorial execution portion of the method).

I'm new to creating my own exceptions and I'm just trying to see if someone with an experienced eye can point out what I'm doing wrong here. to me this should be working right. Thank You!

I've commented in the code where it should be bypassing but is throwing the exception.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RecursiveAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x, y;

        while (true) {
            try {
                x = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a non-negative whole number"));
                System.out.println(x);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("That's not a number! try again!");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                y = factorial(x);
                System.out.println(y);
                break;
            }
            catch (NotAWholeNumber nawn) {
                System.out.println("This is not a whole number! Try again.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There it is");
    }

    public static double factorial(double x) throws NotAWholeNumber {
        if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        System.out.println(x % 2);

        //it's not making it passed this location, when it should... Ive
        //been testing using 5 as my user input every time..

        if (x % 2 != 1.0 || x % 2 != 0.0) {
            throw new NotAWholeNumber("not a whole number");
        }
        else {
            double y = factorial(x - 1) * x;
            return y;
        }
    }
}

public class NotAWholeNumber extends Exception {
    public NotAWholeNumber(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can only accept whole numbers, why not just use an `int` or a `long` and not have to worry about that?

Comment: I'm using a double per assignment instructions, I believe it was to add an extra level of difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and the only mistake I saw is that you have a wrong validation for "whole numbers" (integers).
Just a logic error using "or" ( || ). Here It's needed use "and" (&&), because the MOD division (%) for a positive integer returns 1 or 0, hence, the MOD division (%) has to return a number different of 1 AND 0.

```
public static double factorial(double x) throws NotAWholeNumber {

        if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        System.out.println(x % 2);
        if (x % 2 != 1.0 && x % 2 != 0.0) {
            throw new NotAWholeNumber("not a whole number");
        } else {
            double y = factorial(x - 1) * x;
            return y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that would make it so the throw would always occur converting that to the and `&&` symbol. I'm trying to keep it open for more possible scenarios.

Comment: but holy crap it works when i change it... give me a few minutes to cram my head around this lol...

Comment: I don't know what You want. Your code doesn't throws an error, just an unexpected output. If you are validating for integers, the mod division has to be different of 1 AND 0.

Comment: okay, I understand why this is working now and my way wasn't. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case in which you would want to create your own exception.  Your use case is well-handled by `NumberFormatException`.

The issue here is this line:

```
 if (x % 2 != 1.0 || x % 2 != 0.0)
```

This line doesn't do a good job of checking for whole numbers.

In this scenario, you would be far better served parsing elements as an `Integer` instead, and dealing with the issue at *that* level.

```
try {
    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a non-negative whole number"));
    System.out.println(x);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("That's not a number! try again!");
    continue;
}
```

If you *really* wanted to try it with your own exception though, you could try parsing the value into an `int` inside of your method:

```
public static double factorial(double x) throws NotAWholeNumber {

    try {
        Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(x));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new NotAWholeNumber("Not a whole number!");
    }
    if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return factorial(x - 1) * x;

}
```

...but that is essentially doing two parses when you should only do one.

Alternatively, if you don't mind a little bit of autoboxing, then you could pass a `Double` object in directly and compare its `intValue` against itself.

```
Double x, y
// other code
try {
    x = Double.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a non-negative whole number"));
    System.out.println(x);
}

// other code

public static double factorial(Double x) throws NotAWholeNumber {
    if (x.intValue() - x != 0) {
        throw new NotAWholeNumber("Not a whole number!");
    }
    if (x == 1 || x == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return factorial(x - 1) * x;
}
```

Comment: i agree, using an Int would be far more efficient in this scenario. unfortunately its part of the assignment to use doubles. i believe it was to add an element of difficulty such as this. thank you very much though

Comment: I've already provided a workaround since you're forced to use `Double`.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been more descriptive in my post, the method is also supposed to return a double. But i guess this would work by just converting the int back into a double before returning. thank you very much this would definitely work.

Comment: The method had always returned a double; that never changed.  The only thing that had changed was how we were getting the values into it.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in this line:

```
if (x % 2 != 1.0 || x % 2 != 0.0)
```

says:

```
if x is not an odd number, OR x is not an even number
```

It is true for any `x`, since anything is either not an odd number or not an even number. Possibly you mean `&&` instead of `||`, but it is still a peculiar condition to be checking.

Comment: The whole purpose of that If statement is just to make sure that `x` is a whole number. but when I input a number like 5, it still executes the throw statement inside, when it shouldn't.. right?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you if statement is wrong, it will always return true when x is a whole number, try using this condition instead:

```
if(!(x%2 == 1.0) && !(x%2 == 0.0)){
}
```

Comment: Rewritten, that's `if(!(x % 2 == 1.0) || (x % 2 == 0.0))`, which is always going to be false (the number is either odd or even).

Comment: The conditions is supposed to return false, he wants to test if it is a whole number, not if it is odd or even.

Comment: There's no value in doing that test here, though.  Further, all I've done is rewrite your statement according to DeMorgan's laws.